# ClickOnce deployment creates new installation directory?

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I am using ClickOnce deployment for a Windows App i have. However, when I upload a new version it creates a new installation path and does not reuse the initial path of the first installation?

I am dependent on an auto attached DB that lies in a folder in the first path, so when the update looks for the file it does not find it because it is looking in a folder in the new installation path?

Any idea on how I can force ClickOnce to overwrite the initial installation? I thought that was default ClickOnce behavior, guess I was wrong.

/Bob

Answer (score 0):

When you add the database file to your project, the default `Build Action` for it would be `Content` and in the `Application Files` settings in `Publish` page, the publish status would be `Data File (Auto)`.

While you don't change the database file of the project, when you publish the project and install the new version, the database file of the previous version will be used. But if you change the database file of your project and for example add some table or some test data to it, the new installation which you create using the changed database file will overwrite the previous version database.

In cases that you have some changes in the database file in the project, when you publish and install the application, database of the previous version is still accessible and is copied in a folder named `.pre` in data folder of your application.

You can find the data folder for your installation using:

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

The previous version database mdf and ldf files are available in `.pre` folder under the data directory and you can use them if you want.

Comment: Just for test, in startup of the application, I checked if old files exists, then I copied old mdf and ldf files from the `.pre` folder to main data directory and overwrote them on the new mdf and ldf files. Then removed old mdf and ldf files. This way, regardless of changing the project database file, I could preserve database between installations. But, I recommend you follow the settings which I described in the first two paragraphs of the answer. The case that I described here in comments just was out of curiosity to show how you can use old data files, for example for a data migration.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it useful ...